# compiler steps for method overload resolution

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, overloading

What are the steps followed by a C# Compiler to locate an overload method definition?

let say we have this code :

```
class Test
{
        public void m1(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("int-arg method");
        }
        public void m1(float f)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("float-arg method");
        }
}
 
 
class Program
{
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Test t = new Test();
            t.m1(1);
            t.m1(10.5f);
            t.m1('a');
            t.m1(10L);
            t.m1(10.5); 
        }
}
```

What protocols does the compiler follow to locate the correct method definition?

Comment: [This section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#overload-resolution) of the language spec is basically your answer. Closing as needs more focus.

Comment: If you're asking where the potential surprises come from, that's mostly to do with the [better function member](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#better-function-member) algorithm, which involves comparing conversions between types. Overload resolution is the most complicated part of C#, so you often have to work out individual cases in detail if there is a surprise.